# Alternative domain name and Google Search Console

Tags: dns, domains, google, seo

I have a `mydomain.com` domain that I've been using for years. Recently I purchased `mydomain.it` on which I applied a 301 redirect (`mydomain.it` -> `mydomain.com`).

Do I have to do something on Google Search Console to inform Google that it's just a redirect and avoid penalties?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing more to do since it hasn't been indexed by Google.

301 alone will prevent indexation and penalties

Answer (score 0):

If you've done the 301 correctly, you shouldn't need to worry. However, just to be on the safe side, you can try the following:

- Configure canonical tags on each page in the new site
- Add the new site on Google Search Console (including an updated sitemap)
- Delete the old site on Google Search Console

Comment: Sorry, I probably haven't been clear, `mydomain.it` is not a new site, but a new redirect to `mydomain.com` site.